# Correct way of referring to property of a component in an equation

Tags: diodes, analog, math

What is the correct way of referring to voltage drop of a diode in an equation? For example I want to show the output voltage of the following circuit in an equation **Imagine that the diode is labeled D1**:

[image]

$$
 V_{out} = V_1 - {V{forward}_{D_1}}
$$

So the question is how to refere to voltage drop of the diode above?

as in "Forward voltage drop **of** D1"

Comment: The clearest way is to just label everything on the schematic. For diode forward voltage  people often use \$V_d\$ or \$V_f\$ but there is no hard rule. If multiple diodes exist you need to label the schematic anyways. Your equation is actually rather meaningless without a label on the schematic for the polarity of the diode voltage. It  may seem trivial here but in more complex circuits you won't inherently know the direction beforehand so to solve for it you must define a convention in the schematic.

Comment: @DKNguyen imagine that labels are there. but I want to specificly say the Vf of D1

Comment: It doesn't matter to be honest. There is no one "correct" way. Readability is what is important. But note my previous statement about polarity convention. When I say label, I don't mean label D1. I mean label the actual voltage drop itself so direction/polarity is physically defined. That's what gives your equation meaning.

Comment: Example: Your equation as written assumes the diode voltage drop is labeled  if +on the left and - on the right using passive sign convention. But it could also be - on the left and + on the right and written as \$V_{out} = V_1 + Vforward_{D_1}\$ It's the same how on a physics problem of a vertically tossed ball you can define + or - as up or down. It's arbitrary. You technically don't know the direction of the movements you are solving for until you solve the problem so you can't assign "correct" directions ahead of time for your answer.

Comment: Maybe refer to anode and "k"athode like \$V_{AK}\$ for forward volt drop and, \$V_{KA}\$ for reverse volt drop

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way is to just label everything on the schematic. For diode forward voltage people often use \$V_d\$
or \$V_f\$ but there is no hard rule. If multiple diodes exist you need to label the schematic anyways. There is no one "correct" way. Readability and minimizing misinterpretation is what is important.

When I say label, I don't mean label D1. I mean label the actual voltage drop itself so direction/polarity is physically defined. That's what gives your equation meaning. Your equation is actually rather meaningless without those labels on the schematic for the polarity of the diode voltage (and other voltages). It may seem trivial here but in more complex circuits you won't inherently know the direction beforehand so to solve for it you must define a convention in the schematic.

Example: Your equation as written assumes the diode voltage drop is labeled if +on the left and - on the right using passive sign convention. But it could also be - on the left and + on the right and written as \$V_{out}=V_1+Vforward_{D1}\$

It's the same how on a physics problem of a vertically tossed ball you can define + or - as up or down. It's arbitrary. You technically don't know the direction of the movements you are solving for until you solve the problem so you can't assign "correct" directions ahead of time for your answer by having your equation use the plus or minus for terms in your equation such that the variable in the term ends up being a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official 'correct' way. But, for the average person, a good source of typical industry norms in these situations is manufacturer datasheets.

Looking for a (similar) characteristic across several datasheets from different manufacturers will usually show the same style of notation. That can reassure you that you'd be using an industry-recognised method.

In this instance, I would expect to see:

V<sub>fD1</sub>